# How does the bloomberg website chart calculate the MACD?

Tags: stocks, technical-analysis, market-data, chart, learning

I am looking at [SeekingAlpha](https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/FB/chart) and [Bloomberg](https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/FB:US). 
On SeekingAlpha, I have added the MACD indicator, and get the following chart for 1 Month data:

[image]

On the Bloomberg website, I change the time length to 1-month, and add MACD indicator - and get the following chart:

[image]

Question is why is the MACD different? Bloomberg has a fixed MACD and it cannot be changed. However, SeekingAlpha provides options to modify the MACD calculations (see below). What should be the parameters values to get similar MACD like in Bloomberg's chart?

[image]

Note: Both charts display 1-month data for Facebook as an example.

Answer (score 2):

The time period for each bar is different. For the Bloomberg chart you have it set at daily bars, on the top chart it looks like you have it set at hourly bars. You can tell by the amount of bars on the MACD between each day on each of the charts.

You need to set these at the same time period to get similar looking charts.

Regarding the MACD parameters, if the Bloomberg chart is fixed it would be set at the default parameters, so you shouldn't need to change these on the other chart. You only need to have the time period of each bar set to the same length.

Comment: To the downvoter, who is also downvoting my other answers, why do you think the charts are different? First time I has seen a correct answer (not based on any opinion) downvoted.

Comment: I've up-voted your answer since it seems correct to me.